# Crystal Reports - Count Formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I am developing a report in Crystal and I need to do a count on a particular field that has several different statuses.  For example, I have a "StatusType" field in my report that contains values that are `"In Process", "Rejected", "On Hold", or "Submitted"`.  I want to be able to do a count on the "StatusType" field as to how many values are `"Rejected" and "Submitted"` in one formula.  The report is grouped by `"StatusType"`.

I'm new to writing formulas in Crystal Reports so would appreciate some guidance with getting a formula that will count those two values in the field.  Please let me know what additional information is needed or would be helpful to assist with my question.

I do not need to display the total count for each Status Type at the start/end of each group, but would like to in the page or report header.  I'm not sure which would be best.   I would like to have counts of each status in one spot on the report and then be able to combine a couple of the status counts, such as the `"Rejected"` and `"Submitted"`.  None of the counts I want to display need to be within the body of the report or within the details but rather in the report/page header.

Comment: Do you want to display the total count for each Status Type at the start/end of each group, or elsewhere in the report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best option here would be to use a RunningTotal rather than a formula.

Create a new Running Total and enter the following options:

- Fields to summarize: `{StatusType}`
- Type of Summary: `Count`
- Evaluate: Check `Use a Formula` and press the formula button.
- In the formula box enter `{StatusType} = "Submitted"`
- Reset: Check `Never`

I don't have Crystal installed on this machine at the moment but I think that should do it. Then you can just repeat the process for the `Rejected` status type.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the count of records for each status at the end of each group, you don't need to create a formula. Simply:

- Right-click on the status field.
- Select Insert > Summary... from the menu.
- Select Count as the summary type, and group: status as the summary location within the Insert Summary dialog.
- Click OK at the bottom of the Insert Summary dialog.

This will insert a count of status in the group footer for the status group. You may want to drag it to a more convenient position and/or reformat it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  Is there a way that I can show a combined total for two of the statuses that have a running total.  I would like to be able to show a total of "Rejected" and "Submitted" values in the StatusType field.  If I do the running totals as you indicated what would be next to get the combined total to show in the report?

Comment: @LaTrishaRoman: Barry suggested using running totals, I suggested using a Count field. In either case, it makes a difference **where** in the report you want to place this value, which is why I asked you about it in my comment on your original question. Please can you update your question to include this information, along with whether you want a count of **just** "Rejected" and "Submitted" values, or whether you want to include other values in the count too.