# Is there a way to filter one database field based on another?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have one field which is `{customer.id}` and another which is `{side}` (that has the values "L" and "R") and I need to count the `{customer.id}` if `{side}` is either "L" or "R" but not both(xor) for the specific id.
Example:

```
{customer.id}     {side}
   id1              L
   id1              R
   id2              L
   id2              R
   id3              L
   id4              R 
   id4              R
```

So I would like the result of the distinctcount for this example to be 2 (id3 and id4).

Is it possible to achieve this filtering somehow in crystal reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two running totals for "L" and "R"

- **Fields to summarize:** {customer.id}
- **Type of Summary:** Count
- **Evaluate:** Check Use a Formula and press the formula button.
- In the formula box enter {side} = "L"
- **Reset:** Check Never

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8793138/10191493).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it doesn't quite work for me. I need to count the specific customer if `{side}` is "R" or "L" but not if it is both. Do you think I have to use some sort of SQL Query or is it possible with some crystal reports function?

Comment: I think its possible with sql using group by but i'm not getting there.
Try a formula in crystal like this. 

`IF PREVIOUS({side}) = {side} then 
count({customer.id})`

Comment: Thank you! I think it should work now! Final solution:       **Running total**                                                               **Fields to summarize:** {customer.id}                            **Type of summary:** distinctcount                                  **Evaluate:** Formula:  `({customer.id}<>previous({customer.id}) and {customer.id}<>next({customer.id})) or
({customer.id}=previous({customer.id}) and {side}=previous({side}))`                                                              **Reset:** Check Never. It seems to be correct in my preliminary test period atleast.